# Change cookie value on click issue

Tags: jquery, cookies, click

I'm currently using this code:

```
  $(function () {
      $(".mainmenu a").click(function () {
          $.cookie('value', '0', {
              expires: 365,
              path: '/'
          });
      });
  });
```

This works fine on one directory.

I try to run the same code on another page two directories up, and when clicking on a menu anchor link, this is not changing the value of the cookie.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try setting domain for the cookie :

```
domain: '*.mydomain.com',
```